# What happens when you pre-render a PNG sequence in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have a main timeline with smaller compositions on it. I pre-rendered one of the smaller compositions into a PNG sequence and now the smaller composition is updated on the main timeline as... well, a PNG sequence it looks like.

Why did this happen? How can I get it to go back to being a composition? (Using "Revert" and "Undo" are not options...)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, truly, you got exactly what you asked for, even if that isn't what you wanted.

At this point, just throw away the pre-render and replace that section of the timeline with the original composition. Or pre-render again, with different settings. The original composition is still there.

However, there's a fundamental problem with your action of pre-rendering: when you pre-render a composition, you must do it using the *same final output settings* as your entire video. "Pre-render" means exactly that: you are rendering the same way you will render your final video, but you're doing it in advance to save render time while you're editing other stuff. Take a bit of time out and read the entire [precomposing, nesting and pre-rendering page](http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/precomposing-nesting-pre-rendering.html) in the After Effects online help.

Comment: Thank you!! You're right that I didn't set this file up completely right... thank you so much for providing the extra reading material, its exactly what I was looking for on Google but couldn't find because I didn't know what I was trying to search for.

Comment: I understand completely. Ae isn't the easiest bit of software to wrap the wits around; it's deep, complex, and has plenty of traps for the unwary. :)